# How to sort a matrix by the sum of the rows in C

Tags: c, sorting, matrix

How to sort a matrix by the sum of the rows in C?

For example:

***First matrix is:***

```
M1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
     [9, 10, 11, 12]
     [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I want to get this (descending order):

```
M2 = [9, 10, 11, 12]
     [5, 6, 7, 8]
     [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

***Sum of 1st row*** - `1+2+3+4=10`

***Sum of 2nd row*** - `9+10+11+12=42`

***Sum of 3rd row*** - `5+6+7+8=26`

Sum of 2nd row ***>*** Sum of 3rd row ***>*** Sum of 1st row

***Initial implementation:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("***Program***\n\n");
    int k=4;
    int v=4;
    int M[k][v], i, j, sumrow;
    
    for(i=0; i<k; i++)
        for(j=0; j<v; j++)
        {
            printf("\n%d. row element and %d. column element: ", j+1, i+1);
            scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);  
        }   
    
    printf("\n\n***Print Matrix***:");
    for(i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0; j<v; j++)
        printf("%d ", M[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        sumrow=0;
        for(j=0; j<v; j++)
            sumrow+=M[i][j];
        printf("\nSum of %d. row : %d", i+1, sumrow);   
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: Do you have an initial implementation?

Comment: What are you stuck at? Please focus on one of the following problems: a) storing a matrix correctly b) sorting a simple array of ints c) determining sum of rows d) swapping two rows For all those problems you do NOT have a problem with, please provide a [mre], to make helping you with your immediate problem easier.

Comment: You can write a comparator that can be used with the standard C `qsort()` function.  It's not particularly easy, not least because you have to compute the row sum for each row each time it is compared (slow if the matrix is wide), and you can't get useful (important) information like the row size passed as parameters to the function. If you're writing your own sorting code, you can precompute the row sums, and then sort the array of row sums and the matrix in parallel.  But you've not shown where you're having problems. You need to show what you've tried and explain where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Just in case that this is homework-related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int *row, int size) {
    int s = 0;
    for (size--; size >= 0; size--) s += row[size];
    return s;
}

int main() {
    int matrix[3][4] = {{1, 2,  3,  4},
                        {9, 10, 11, 12},
                        {5, 6,  7,  8}};

    int tmp;

    printf("Before:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Bubble sort.
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++) {
            // Comparing row value.
            if (sum(matrix[i], 4) > sum(matrix[j], 4)) {
                // Swapping.
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    tmp = matrix[i][k];
                    matrix[i][k] = matrix[j][k];
                    matrix[j][k] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("After:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
1 2 3 4
9 10 11 12
5 6 7 8
After:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

Some insights:

- My implementation relays on a 2D array.
- Use a comparison function to make it more clear.
- Since these are not pointers, the swapping needs to be item by item, can be optimized if it would use pointers for example.